# USB C splitter with two charge for 2 usb monitors

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, usb-host, usb-hub

I have a laptop with 2 USB C ports only. I want to be able to continue charging the laptop via one of the USB C ports and then use the remaining USB C port to split two directions, so that it provides separate, distinctly different data for two different external USB C monitors. The split needs to also provide power to both external monitors.

I've looked into a USB hub for this, but can't find one that provides two USB C ports outputting charge and data.

Any ideas?

[image: Power to Computer to external monitors]

Comment: Are you talking about [this situation with USB Type-C](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/charging-via-usb-c/)?

Comment: Does that image help? Laptop has only two ports.

Comment: It helps me a little. But I'm still not certain. Are you saying you want to continue charging the laptop via one of the USB C ports and that you want to use the remaining USB C port to split two directions, so that it provides separate, distinctly different data for two different external USB C monitors? This would suggest to me that there has to be a laptop driver that combines signaling and then a separate splitter that can divert that combined stream in two different directions according to programming for same. All while maintaining USB Type-C behavior. Is that it? (Sounds like a hub.)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after, but Hubs aren't working to then power the monitors. They are meant to be powered by USB C and I can't find hubs that have 2 ports catering for Power and data exchange

Comment: Well, I don't have any ideas. At least I feel I gather the question better. Perhaps someone else may, perhaps helped by this discussion. You may want to include some of it in your own words into the question rather than in comments below it. But that's up to you.  (If you do improve the question with a better discussion, I'll +1 the question, too.)

Comment: Thanks for helping to clarify the question. I have updates my original post - hopefully it helps

Comment: Ollie, that's good enough. I'll +1 it. I don't have any added thoughts. But at least I think the problem is posed. (It may still be called a "shopping question." But that's a different issue. At least it is written well enough for now.)

Comment: Thanks Jonk, appreciate the "shoppiness" of the question, but I am more interested to know if it is even possible to have a USB C to many USB C ports splitter whereby power and data can exchange?

Comment: Well, the *possibility* side of the question is less *shopping-like*. So that might work better here. :)

Comment: Do your monitors only have a single USB-C port? Are you sure your laptop supports two external monitors? Are you sure your monitors can be powered via USB-C? What’s the rating of the power supply? A decent laptop + two screens is a lot of power… References and specs of the laptop and the monitors would probably help a lot.

Comment: Yeah, the monitors have 2 USC-C ports and a mini HDMI only. My chromebook can support both monitors and power them both concurrently. The issue is I can't charge the computer and power both monitors at the same time due to a lack of ports on the computer

Answer (score 1):

Other World Computing recently released a USB-C/Thunderbolt hub that should work for you.
https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-hub

It's advertised as a Thunderbolt hub but I have one and it works fine as a USB 3.x hub.  I have not tested the video capability but they claim the hub supports two 4K displays.  It supplies up to 60 watts to the host and 15 watts to peripherals.  With that you may not need the separate power supply to the laptop, that frees up a port.

The reason you would not see hubs like this earlier, as I understand it, is that the function of USB-C hubs was ambiguous until USB4 came out.  Then once the spec was released it took time for people to build products to the spec.

I have no relationship with Other World Computing than being a customer.  They have other hubs that may work, check their website.  I expect other places offer similar products or will soon.  I linked to that product to show such devices exist by giving an example.  In case of a dead link later I'll say it is a USB-C/Thunderbolt hub with four USB-C ports and one USB-A port.  One USB-C port is the host port, this provides more power than the others.  It's about the size of two iPhone 8 phones stacked flat, and comes with a power brick that is bit larger than that.